# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null at t.ngOnInit

Tags: angular

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bodyClassChangeService.onScroll();
    const app = document.querySelector('.inipay_modal-backdrop')
    app.remove();
    const p = document.querySelector('#inicisModalDiv')
    p.remove();
}
```

why this error happen?
.inipay_modal-backdrop is class name.
#inicisModalDiv is id name

Comment: Obviouslly, element #inicisModalDiv can't be query in ngOnInit lifecycle. Maybe you will need to retrieve that in ngAfterViewInit lifecycle.

Comment: What @KevinZhang said. Also, don't query directly. Use `ViewChild` to access element, or use `Renderer2` if you have no choice but query element.